# shortening multiple if conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var pageTypeArray = [];
var win = window.location.href;
if (win.match(".*product.*")) {
  pageTypeArray.push("productDetail");
}
if (win.match(".*login.*")) {
  pageTypeArray.push("login");
}
if (win.match(".*loan. *")) {
  page TypeArray.push("loanDetail");
}
if (win.match(". *reward.*")) {
  pageTypeArray.push("reward");
}
if (win.match("^(?!.* (product|login|loan reward)). *$")) {
  pageTypeArray.push("uncategorized");
}
```

If I were to add many more conditions how can I improve (shorten) this code?

Answer (score 2):

You could maintain an array of types and matches and then filter/map that array to create the `pageTypeArray`.

```js
const win = window.location.href;

const matchArr = [
  { type: "productDetail", match: ".*product.*" },
  { type: "login", match: ".*login.*" },
  { type: "loanDetail", match: ".*loan. *" },
  { type: "reward", match: ". *reward.*" },
  { type: "uncategorized", match: "^(?!.* (product|login|loan reward)). *$" }
];

const pageTypeArray = matchArr
  .filter(({ match }) => win.match(match))
  .map(({ type }) => type);
```

Comment: Haha I actually wrote the exact same code in the answer I was typing, down to the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of regular expressions instead - and use *actual regular expressions* if you want to perform regex tests, not strings.

Also, I'm pretty that

```
".*loan. *"
```

and

```
". *reward.*"
```

are typos - if you just wanted to match any string with `loan` and `reward` in them, just use the regular expression `/loan/` or `/reward/`.. (Your first `loan` will match `loan` followed by any character, followed by zero or more spaces. Your `reward` will match any character, followed by zero or more spaces, followed by `reward`. That doesn't sound like what you need.

```
const patterns = [
    [/product/, 'productDetail'],
    [/login/, 'login'],
    [/loan/, 'loanDetail'],
    [/^(?!.* (product|login|loan reward)). *$/, 'uncategorized'],
];
const pageTypeArray = [];
const { href } = window.location;
for (const pattern of patterns) {
    if (pattern[0].test(href)) {
        pageTypeArray.push(pattern[1]);
    }
}
```

`loan reward` in your original code may be a typo too - did you mean to put a `|` between those? If so - if `uncategorized` is meant to exist when nothing else matches - then ditch the regular expressions entirely and just use `String#includes`:

```
const patterns = [
    ['product', 'productDetail'],
    ['login', 'login'],
    ['loan', 'loanDetail'],
];
const pageTypeArray = [];
const { href } = window.location;
for (const pattern of patterns) {
    if (href.includes(pattern[0])) {
        pageTypeArray.push(pattern[1]);
    }
}
if (pageTypeArray.length === 0) {
    pageTypeArray.push('uncategorized');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you this approach :

```js
const win = window.location.href;
const SCHEMA = [
  {
    reg: ".*product.*",
    action: "productDetail",
  },
  {
    reg: ".*login.*",
    action: "login",
  },
  {
    reg: ".*loan. *",
    action: "loanDetail",
  },
  {
    reg: ". *reward.*",
    action: "reward",
  },
  {
    reg: "^(?!.* (product|login|loan reward)). *$",
    action: "uncategorized",
  }
];

const elmts = SCHEMA.filter((elm) => {
  return win.match(elm.reg);
});

const pageTypeArray = elmts.map((val) => {
  return val.action;
});
```